# Every time I launch tests, asp.net mvc project starts building

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, build

I have a problem: when I launch my asp.net mvc application it always starts building even without any changes. I found that I can't prevent this, but it bothers me when a launch tests too. Project isn't REbuilt and it skips already built files, but even so it takes about 30-40 seconds for each launching.

Please help me to find out how can I launch my application or at least tests without building project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem is resolved by deleting the  YourProject.suo   file. This file is hidden.

but first get Backup fully from your project!

Be sure to back up the project before doing it

This file is recreated

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help

Comment: When the project is closed, delete this file and then launch it.
It will quickly open the project
I've tested several times and made a very good result

Comment: Not solution opening time is an issue but solution build on every launch of test